# How can you use different properties in android xml files according to api version?

Tags: android, android-styles

I am creating a project that uses a big number of icons, in order to support multiple screens easily, I created the icons using vector graphics (SVG paths I believe they are called) which worked ok in my device.

Unfortunately when I tried to use it on older devices (anything with android less than 5.0) I get an inflater exception.

After searching I found out that in order to use vector graphics for those devices instead of using

```
android:src
```

I have to use

```
app:srcCompat
```

this indeed fixed the problem, but now when I deploy it to a newer device, the icons won't show (at least it doesn't crash though, so that's something)

Is there a way to define some sort of style to use according to api version

so that I can do something along the lines of :

```
<style name="android.api.21">
    <item name="android:src">ic_menu</item>
</style>

<style name="android.api.19">
    <item name="app:srcCompat">ic_menu</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Not sure if you can do something like this... But you can have different layout for different API

Comment: yeah that would help, it would be much more annoying to update two layouts instead of one, but I guess if it can't be done using styles I'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: By the way, are you using compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0', I'm not sure it is because fo this, but I'm able to use android:src for all API>14 for vector drawable. But be aware that before API21 the svg will be converted to corresponding png in the apk

Comment: unfortunatelly I'm using Xamarin, and we only got up to version 23.3, I'll give it a try when 23.4 comes out for xamarin

Comment: yeah it seems to work with appcompat, but there are problems when I try to retrieve a vector drawable using ContextCompat.GetDrawable so I'm hoping that this is some sort of Xamarin bug. So I'm gonna go with the values thing and if it gets fixed I'll replace it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the same style name (for example, styles.xml) and in resources folder (app/main/res) create different folders with naming **values** (common version), **values-v21** (for API 21, Lolipop 5.0), **values-v19** (API 19, KitKat 4.4) and so on and so forth.